# Using the digital snake with the X32

Tags: mixer

If I use one S16 digital snake with the X32, can I route it with channels 17 thru 32 and outputs 9 thru 16?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can!  Each block of 8 can be sourced regardless of the label. You could map the 17-24 section to any of the AES blocks (meaning 17-24 could be mapped to AES50 A1-8).